# What term describes this sentence structure with preposition and possible gerund?

Tags: gerunds, syntactic-analysis, verb-forms

What is the correct grammatical description for this sentence?

> I need help taking out an old hard drive.

I am most interested in whether the verb "take" is a gerund here, and how to describe the proceeding clause. It may be a prepositional-gerundial construction, but I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: What does "prepositional-gerundial construction" mean?

Comment: What do you hope to learn from this question? You should try to generalise your question so that people are encouraged to answer with more than *no*.

Comment: Hello vixtor! I edited your question slightly, in order to make it answerable with more than a yes or no, as @MattЭллен recommended. Please see if that captures the intent of your question. Could you clarify what you mean by "prepositional-gerundial"? I don't know what that means.

Comment: Probably a nonce term that sounds impressive and means they're adverbial gerund clauses and can take optional prepositions. I gotta admit, "prepositional-gerundial" sounds cool. Like _complex catenative,_ which means it's complicated and it's linked together.

Answer (score 1):

At http://www.englishforums.com/English/VerbObjIngForm/nqrbz/post.htm are descriptions of two different but identical-looking structures of the **Verb + obj + -ing-form** form:

(1) She caught Tom smoking.

(2) She needed help walking.

The first is a complex catenative ( http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YNfzbWuMFuoC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=complex+catenative&source=bl&ots=PXamBDZhQk&sig=x4zwAVO1mnZ-oYlpXJRdWDFQVS4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ErTRUcDRA6mK7Aanr4CADg&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAw ).

The second really uses a two-word idiom (*need help*); it is, as CJ in the first link above says, not best analysed as part of a catenative structure. He gives further examples, and another pair of look-alikes are:

(3) She took Bill walking.

(4) She took care walking.

Several of these verb + noun collocations / idioms (take care, make haste, lose no time, have fun...) regularly take ing-forms (usually themselves followed by noun groups). I'd say these ing-forms were a lot nearer the verbal end of the continuum than the nounal (so I would never call them *gerunds*).

Comment: I'd just call all but the last one reduced adverbial clauses; note that one can insert prepositions and/or subordinate conjunctions in most of these cases. _She caught Tom (in (the act of)/while (he was)) smoking, She needed help (in/while) walking, She took care (in/while) walking_. The _take_ construction is different, part of the _come/go_ + V(-_ing_) idiom cluster: _go eat, go shooting, come dance, come dancing, bring her dancing, take him shooting,_ etc.

Comment: That's "the next-to-last one" (3) that's special. Sorry.

Comment: You may have to pay the penultimate penalty.